# Where to find Emerald Dust in White Orchard?

Tags: the-witcher-3

In White Orchard I got a quest for the Viper School swords.

I finished it and I got 2 diagrams for crafting 2 swords, a Silver one and a Steel one.

I went to the Nilfgaardian Encampment and spoke to the quartermaster and he could make
them but I don't have any **Emerald Dust**.

I would love to use the swords in White Orchard because they seem really strong.

**Is there any way of getting Emerald Dust in White Orchard?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can buy Emerald Dust from that very same Quartermaster but I wouldn't advise it since it's really expensive. You can easily get **Emerald Dust** from **killing Wraiths**.

In White Orchard there are a total of 4 Wraiths.

Since you say you have already the diagrams for the swords I assume you've already fought the **2 lvl.7 Wraiths** in the **Cemetery** (One by the Place of Power and one inside the Crypt). If they don't drop Emerald Dust you still have 2 wraiths left.

One you can kill doing the quest **"Devil By the Well"**. Do it and loot the Emerald Dust from the Wraith.

For the last Wraith it's actually close to the **Nilfgaard Garrison** and it's in a Place of Power. Go there and a Wraith will appear to protect it. Kill it and retrieve the Emerald Dust.

You can use [this](http://guides.gamepressure.com/thewitcher3/guide.asp?ID=30666) as an interactive map and in case the link goes dead here is the location:

[image: Wraith Location]

I did this and it worked like a charm.

Each sword only needs 1 Emerald Dust so you should be good to go if you have the other ingredients.

Comment: It might be worth saving your game before fighting either of these wraiths, so if they don't drop the emerald dust you can reload your save and fight them again until they do.

Comment: Mostly correct... but there are 3, not 4 wraiths. The Devil by the Well quest is the same wraith, you chase it away from the place of power and into the crypt, where you can kill it, i.e. you fight it twice, but can only get loot from it once. Good tip from @Pyritie, wish I'd known I needed this drop twice (for two serpentine swords) before I killed the third and got just one drop! :-)

Comment: its 4 wraiths. The Devil By The Well one, the Place of Power one, and the 2 Cemetery Wraiths......

Comment: There is only one wraith in the cemetery. After dropping it to about half health it retreats into the crypt.

Comment: Save your game before you fight the wraiths, the emerald dust is a low drop chance. All other posts seem to imply that it is guaranteed to drop, but it took me 6 tries to get the dust.

Answer (score 2):

I just found 2 of them in random loot in White Orchard. Fast travel to Ford, follow the road south from there until you get to a bridge over the river. Under the bridge are lootable packages.

Answer (score 1):

It's the Devil by the Well wraith, the Place of Power wraith, the Cemetery/Crypt wraith are one and the same as Gallus stated.  The Cemetery/Crypt wraith has never dropped anything for me on 3 playthroughs now.